# Change var in object literal function

Tags: javascript, object-literal

Hi guys I am writing some code using the object literal pattern, I have function that returns a value:

```
'currentLocation': function() {
    var cL = 0;
    return cL;
    },
```

I then need to update the variable 'cL' from another function like this:

```
teamStatus.currentLocation() = teamStatus.currentLocation() + teamStatus.scrollDistance();
```

This part is part of another function - however I get an error back stating: invalid assignment left-hand side

I am guessing I can not update the variable in this way, could anyone suggest a better method or point me in the right direction.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Going to add more code to highlight what I am trying to do:

```
'currentLocation': function() {
    var cL = 0;
    return cL;
    },
'increaseTable': function() {
    if (teamStatus.currentLocation() <= teamStatus.teamStatusTableHeight() ) {
        teamStatus.currentLocation = teamStatus.currentLocation() + teamStatus.scrollDistance();
        $("#tableTrackActual").animate({scrollTop: (teamStatus.currentLocation)});
        $("#tableMembers").animate({scrollTop: (teamStatus.currentLocation) });
        //console.log(teamStatus.currentLocation());
        teamStatus.buttonRevealer();
    }
}
```

As you can see increaseTable should update the value of currentLocation  - help this sheds more light on what I am trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

You're writing `teamStatus.currentLocation() =`, which calls the function `teamStatus.currentLocation` and tries to assign to the return value. That isn't valid. You want just `teamStatus.currentLocation =` — no function call.

Comment: Cheers Chuck think you were right got a quick test then will mark your answer as correct. you rock dude

Answer (score 0):

The variable inside your function is completely private to that function (and any functions defined within it). If you need to create a number of functions that share a set of private variables, you can do that with a closure. For instance:

```
var Thing = (function() {
    var thingWideData;

    function getData() {
        return thingWideData;
    }

    function setData(newData) {
        thingWideData = newData;
    }

    return {
        getData: getData,
        setData: setData
    };

})();
```

What that does is create a `Thing` object which has `getData` and `setData` functions available for it, which get and set the *completely private* `thingWideData` variable contained by the anonymous closure. More about this pattern [here](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2010/03/anonymouses-anonymous.html) and [here](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2009/09/private-methods-in-javascript.html), although the latter of those is more about private methods than private data.

Answer (score 0):

What your code produces is:

```
0 = 0 + <some number>
```

Which variable do you want to update? `cL`? You are declaring it in the function, you cannot assign a value to it from outside. Depending on the rest of your code, you might be better off with [`getters and setters`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Working_with_Objects#Defining_Getters_and_Setters):

```
var object = {
    _cL = 0,
    get currentLocation() {
        return this._cL;
    },
    set currentLocation(value) {
        this._cL = value;
    }
}
```

then you can do:

```
teamStatus.currentLocation = teamStatus.currentLocation + teamStatus.scrollDistance();
```

**Update:**

Regarding IE: If `currentLocation` should actually be just a number, it might be sufficient to just declare it as property:

```
var obj = {
    currentLocation: 0
}
```

Comment: Hi currentLocation does need to be just a value but i need to be able to update its value

Comment: @jonathan p: Then you can declare it to just be a number instead of being a function :) (as shown in the update).